# JMeter Dashboard HTML Report - exclude completely unwanted requests

Tags: java, html, performance, jmeter, report

My test has 20 requests, but 5 of them I've excluded using filter jmeter property:
**jmeter.reportgenerator.exporter.html.series_filter**

However the dashboard still counts the metrics in table headers:

[image]

Is it possible to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to completely remove the "unwanted" results it's better to remove them from the .jtl file.

The options are in:

1. Add [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) as a child of the request(s) you don't "want" to see and put the following [Groovy](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) code into "Script" area:

   ```
   prev.setIgnore()
   ```

   where `prev` stands for **prev**ious [SampleResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html)
2. Use [Filter Results Tool](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/FilterResultsTool/) which has `--include-labels` and `--exclude-labels` parameters allowing you to specify what needs to be included or excluded from the .jtl results file.